# AppleScript : keystroke : too slow

Tags: applescript, keystroke

The keystroke on my script take around 5/7 seconds until going to the next step.
I didn't set any delay.

E.g :

```
-- Click 1
    click pop up button 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 1 of group 2 of group 6 of group 2 of group 1 of group 4 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
    keystroke "Edit"
    keystroke return
    -- Click 2
    click pop up button 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 6 of group 2 of group 1 of group 4 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
    keystroke "Standard"
    keystroke return
```

So basically, its clicking, show the Click Pop up button, wait 7 secondes, then continue the script.

Any idea?

Comment: Can't really test along with you without knowing what app this is in. (a custom one of your own creation?) Seeing the keystroke command right after the click command raising red flags for me about the proper first responder. Does the pop up button place the cursor in the text area? Does the click visibly happen and THEN the 7 seconds, or otherwise?

Comment: Please tell us what application you are targeting

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, It's a enterprise app. I guest its because of the app and can do nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get your hopes up, but you can try to wrap problem lines in `time out` or `ignoring application responses`.

```
try
    with timeout of x seconds
        --
    end timeout
end try
```

.

```
ignoring application responses
    --
end ignoring
```